# How to copy a (ICU4C) Unicode string to another Unicode string character by character?

Tags: c++, unicode, icu, icu4c

I'm trying to use ICU's `StringCharacterIterator` to copy (and possibly alter) characters from a source string to a destination string. However, I am having unexpected results and am unsure why.

I would expect the final line of output of this program to be `dog` but instead I get `og∩┐┐`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <icu4c/unicode/schriter.h>

int main()
{
    UnicodeString dog = UnicodeString::fromUTF8("dog");
    StringCharacterIterator chars(dog);

    UnicodeString copy;
    while(chars.hasNext())
        copy.append(chars.next32());

    for(int i=0; i<copy.countChar32(); i++)
    {
        int32_t charNumber = copy.char32At(i);
        std::cout << charNumber << "\n";
    }

    std::string stdString;
    copy.toUTF8String(stdString);
    std::cout << stdString;
}
```

**Program Output**

```
111
103
65535
og∩┐┐
```

**Unicode table**

111 - latin small letter o

103 - latin small letter g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `StringCharacterIterator::hasNext` returns false only when the iterator is beyond the end of the string.
2. `StringCharacterIterator::next32` advances the current position of the iterator and returns the new code point.  It is analogous to `*(++it)` for a raw pointer or standard library style iterator.

Taken together, this means you're skipping the first character of your string and reading an extra character beyond the end.

You can use `next32PostInc`, which behaves like `*(it++)` for a raw pointer or standard library iterator, instead of `next32`:

```
while(chars.hasNext())
    copy.append(chars.next32PostInc());
```